# passenger error Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter`, ruby 1.9.2 rails 2.3.8

Tags: passenger

i have a problem - i have Ubuntu 12.04 server and I am trying to host ruby on rails app on it.

I have chosen passenger with apache. I have installed RVM and made gemset "ruby-1.9.2-p320@myapp" and it works. I have really old rails 2.3.8 app, which is just for archive for me and I dont have any time to update it.

I have passenger error `Please install the mysql2 adapter: 'gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter' (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter)`

My "gem list":

```
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
bundler (1.2.3)
daemon_controller (1.1.1)
fastthread (1.0.7)
mislav-will_paginate (2.3.11)
mysql2 (0.2.7)
passenger (3.0.19)
rack (1.1.6)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (10.0.3)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubygems-update (1.8.25, 1.3.5)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
thoughtbot-paperclip (2.3.1)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

I can using `ruby script/console` get to database records, so connection with database is established and it WORKS.

Is there any ideas for solution?
Thank you.

If any extra info is needed, it will be provided asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was misconfiguration of Passenger and Apache from my part.
Just follow these loveley tutorial and all will be OK: http://everydayrails.com/2010/09/13/rvm-project-gemsets.html

And if you afterwards run into problems of UTF-8 errors for older rails apps, just read on that here: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=42009